# how to merge these two SQL queries?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Schema: http://pastebin.com/jU3HmmNM

```
$mainfetch = "SELECT * FROM status ORDER BY status_id DESC LIMIT 10,0";

while($mainfetch -> $result) {
  $subquery = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM status s, likes l WHERE s.status_id = l.status_id AND l.member_id = 1;
$liked = $query->row();
if($liked > 0) {
//liked
}else {
//not liked
}
}
```

So this is not optimal as $subquery will execute each time 10 times, I wish to add $subquery to $mainfetch, how can I join them two?

Comment: This looks like mysql instead of sql server. Either way, you should use the "newer" join syntax introduced in ANSI-92.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a left join on `s.status_id = l.status_id`... And then you get also the `l.status_id`: if it is null, then member 1 not liked it, otherwise yes of course.

Comment: no group by? Because I was told to use Group By, I have some additional conditions in WHERE clause, but that wont be affected? Also how can I get alias name, such as I did with $subquery? Something like SELECT COUNT(*) AS is_liked ?

Comment: Why do you need a group by? Your DB can store only one row in the likes table with a given couple  (status id and member id), can't it? You can get alias names in the same way: `select s.*, l.status_id as liked from status s left join likes l ...` and you just need to check wether liked is null or not..

Answer (score 0):

Using the schema you provided:

```
SELECT s.status_id, s.text_id, count(l.status_id) as like_count
FROM status AS s LEFT JOIN likes AS l ON (s.status_id = l.status_id AND l.member_id = 1) 
group by s.status_id, s.text_id
ORDER BY status_id DESC
LIMIT 10,0
```

Comment: Thank you, I solved it little easier, without count, I just joined two fields and checked if is_liked not null in my php application. Ill consider this solution too.